# I'm trying to test a api request from a service using jasmine with angular, but with no success

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

when i try to compare the response with the object who is being returned from the server, it returns a error message saying that Expected undefined to equal Object({ data: '2019-11-21T13:00:03.070Z', desconhecido: false, id: 21214, ip: '444.444.44.44', nomeUsuario: 'rodrigo.spinelli', sucesso: true, usuarioId: 1414, usuarioNome: 'rodrigo abreu' }).:

```
beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
          providers: [AcessoService]
        });

        httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        service = TestBed.get(AcessoService);
      });

      afterEach(() => {
        httpTestingController.verify();
      });


      const profileInfo = {
        data: new Date('2019-11-21T10:00:03.07').toISOString(),
        desconhecido: false,
        id: 21214,
        ip: '444.444.44.44',
        nomeUsuario: 'rodrigo.spinelli',
        sucesso: true,
        usuarioId: 1414,
        usuarioNome: 'rodrigo abreu'
      };

        const index = '1';
        const itemsPage = '1';
        const usuarioId = '';
        const nomeUsuario = '';
        const dataIni = new Date('2019-11-01T18:25:39.000Z').toISOString();
        const dataFim = new Date('2019-11-30T18:25:39.000Z').toISOString();
        const ip = '';
        const sucesso = '';
        const orderBy = '';

        let Acessos;


      it('can load instance', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('getDepartmentMapping() should return data', () => {

        service.getAcessos(index, itemsPage, '', '', dataIni, dataFim, '', '', '').subscribe(res => {
          Acessos = res.items;
        });

      expect(Acessos).toEqual(profileInfo);
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because getAccessos has an async behaviour. It returns an Observable and you subscribe to it as well. When it next data for you you get the result in the context but not outside of it. Accessos is undefined outside of subscribe's resolve function.

Try it like this:

```
...
it('getDepartmentMapping() should return data', async () => {
  Acessos = await service.getAcessos(index, itemsPage, '', '', dataIni, dataFim, '', '', '').pipe(take(1)).pipe(map((res) => { return res.items; })).toPromise();
  expect(Acessos).toEqual(profileInfo);
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
  it('getDepartmentMapping() should return data', (done) => {
     service.getAcessos(index, itemsPage, '', '', dataIni, dataFim, '', '', '').subscribe(res => {
        expect(res.items).toEqual(profileInfo);
        done();
    });
  });
```